# Generalising a conditional query in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am working on IBM DB2. I have a query:

```
select temp.dv,
    max(case when att.id=100 then  temp.en else '0' end) as cl,
    max(case when att.id=103 then  temp.en else null end) as mo,
    max(case when att.id=104 then  temp.en else null end) as do,
from temp left outer join att on att.id=temp.id where doc=100
```

How do I generalise this for all values of `att.id`?

Comment: It needs more detail. Each example of a `att.id` value shows a different result. Therefore, there can be no possible "generalise ... for all values". The example doesn't demonstrate generalization, but rather specialization. Multiple samples of input data showing expected results is probably needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the values pivoted, then you can copy the column names into Excel and generate the correct syntax.  You could also put the SQL statement into a string and then run that (called dynamic SQL in other databases).

If you don't need them pivoted, then you can put the results on separate lines using `group by`:

```
select temp.dv,
       att.id,
       max(temp.en)
    max(case when att.id=104 then  temp.en else null end) as do,
from temp left outer join
     att
     on att.id=temp.id
where doc=100
group by temp.dv, att.id
```

Comment: Could you show how I will use dynamic sql on this? I don't have a lot of experience with sql.

Comment: @khateeb . . . I do not have experience with prepared statements in DB2.  The documentation is here (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sql_prepare.htm).